404 - File or directory not found. getting in windows server
I am using React for the frontend and .NET Core for the backend. Everything works fine in the local environment, but when I deploy into windows server, I get a 404 - File or Directory Not Found error. I haven't been able to find a solution. Please help me.

Too many details are missing. 1) URL for this 404 page? 2) How exactly did you deploy? The steps are important as typical mistakes can be made.

React uses client-side routing, but IIS (or any server) handles server-side routing. Make sure you're configuring your server to serve the index.html for all routes. You can do this by updating the web.config file if you're using IIS:
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>

